# Can you use \U \L or similar to change case with the batch rename tool?

Tags: python, scripting, rigging

I tried, and computer said no, but here's hoping I was doing something wrong:

In some regex implementations you can use `\Un` and `\Ln` to change the case of a matched group `n`.

e.g. given the name `mch.Leg.l` you can use the regex `(mch)\.(\a)(a*)\.([RL])` and the replacement pattern `\U1.\U2\3.\U4` to turn it into `MCH.Leg.L`

Is there any way of doing that using the batch renamer, or will I have to write a script?

Comment: As far as I understand it, any kind of batch renamer would be using python expressions anyway, and I do not recognize these expressions as implemented in python. I could be very wrong, though. I do think writing a script would actually be easier in this case to the point that I could almost put it in the comments. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I was just cleaning up a rig, where some of the bones were labelled with caps and some not. So I wanted all the names to follow the same pattern.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like python doesn't support it, so I'll have to use the string methods like `upper()` in a script.